# getElementById() and input form

Tags: javascript, forms, input, user-input, getelementbyid

I have a

```
function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
}
```

And then a

```
<select id="start" onchange="calcRoute();">
  <option value="somevalue">Dropdown 1</option>
  <option value="somevalue">Dropdown 2</option>
  <option value="somevalue">Dropdown 3</option>
</select>
```

Everything works properly. Now, instead of a dropdown list I need an input box. The problem is that I tried with

```
<form onsubmit="calcRoute();" method="get" id="start" action="#">
<input type="text" id="start" name="start">
<input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

But it doesn't work (it's submitting the form to the server).. you can see a demo [**here**](http://ffio.it/test.html). Remember that I don't need the dropdown list (it's there only to prove everything works), so it can go (there's no problem of double-called function). Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same id, inputs do not have onsubmit attributes etc.

Comment: I set the 2 elements (dropdown and input box) to let you see the dropdown works (whereas input box doesn't). Take a look here (no dropdown): http://ffio.it/test4.html

Comment: the input element's id is (startText instead of start) wrong. Look at my answer below.

Comment: startText was an error when I typed this question. The code on the page is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change from:

```
<input type="text" id="startText" name="start">
```

To:

```
<input type="text" id="start" name="start">
```

As Javascript is searching for ID, not for name. (and in your code the ID is different from what Javascript is searching)

If you want use the input and the dropdown list in the same page, you just change your variable definition to something as:

```
var start = document.getElementById('startText').value || document.getElementById('start').value;
```

As if the input is empty, Javascript uses the value from the dropdown list.

**Update**

In adition to the change of the ID, change your form to something as:

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="start" name="start">
    <input type="button" onclick="calcRoute();" value="Go">
</form>
```

To not allow form submission.

Comment: If you use the dropdown list in the same page, just change the ID from the input and from what javascript searches..(for no conflict of names)

Comment: I don't need the dropdown list in the same page. I just put them in the demo to let you see it works (whereas input box doesn't).
Anyway I made your change but still doesn't seem to work :( -> http://ffio.it/test4.html

Comment: Ok now the form is not submitted. But nothing seems to happen.. :) -> http://ffio.it/test4.html

Comment: From console: TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno Oh, update the form newly according to the question. I have missed that i not changed the ID of the input text.

Comment: Yessssss!! Works!! I'll accept this answer as soon as I'm allowed to (2 minutes). ;)